# Счетчик в slick slider

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Помогите поправить счетчик в slick slider. Слайдер должен листать по три картинки за раз при этом на счетчике должно быть +1, а не +3 как сейчас.
И никак не могу сделать, чтобы число, которое увеличивается делало это через JS (сейчас прописано в HTML)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.slider-new').slick({
    arrows: true,
    nextArrow: $('.next'),
    prevArrow: $('.prev'),
    infinite: false,
    slidesToShow: 3,
    slidesToScroll: 3
  });
});
$(".slider-new").on('afterChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide) {
  if (currentSlide == 0) {
    $("#count").text("0" + (currentSlide + 1));
  } else {
    $("#count").text("0" + (currentSlide + 1));
  }

});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.slider-birthday').slick({
    arrows: true,
    nextArrow: $('.next2'),
    prevArrow: $('.prev2'),
    infinite: false,
    slidesToShow: 3,
    slidesToScroll: 3
  });
});
$(".slider-birthday").on('afterChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide) {
  if (currentSlide == 0) {
    $("#count2").text("0" + (currentSlide + 1));
  } else {
    $("#count2").text("0" + (currentSlide + 1));
  }

});
```

```css
.main__section--slider {
  margin: 20px 0px 0px 10px;
  background: #f8f8f8;
  padding: 0px 0px 20px 0px;
}

.owl-item {
  width: 10%;
}

.main__section--collegues,
.main__section--birthday {
  width: 49%;
  float: left;
  margin: 2em 0px 1.1em;
  position: relative;
}

.main__section--birthday {
  border-left: 1px solid grey;
}

.collegues__list,
.collegues__birthday {
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
}

.collegues__list-el {
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.collegues__title {
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

.collegues__firstname,
.collegues__surname {
  margin: 0px;
}

.collegues__name {
  font: bold 14px/1.1 'Stolzl', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

.collegues__name-link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
}

.collegues__name-link:active {
  color: #000;
}

.collegues__position {
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.collegues__date,
.collegues__position {
  font: normal 14px/1.1 'Stolzl', sans-serif;
  color: grey;
}

.collegues__birthday>.owl-nav:hover {
  color: #00a85d;
}

.collegues__block--image {}

.collegues__image {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
}


/*---------------------
---------CLEARFIX------
----------------------*/

.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}


/*----------------------
---------ARROW----------
-----------------------*/

.owl-next:hover,
.owl-prev:hover {
  border-color: #00a85d;
}

.slider__next,
.slider__prev {
  width: 3em;
  height: 2px;
  background: grey;
  border: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
}

.slider__prev {
  right: 50%;
}

.slider__next {
  left: 50%;
}

.navigation__btn {
  position: relative;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid grey;
  margin: 0px 3.5em 0px 3.5em;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.navigation__btn:hover {
  border-color: #00a85d;
}

.slider__prev::after {
  content: "";
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(135deg);
  left: 2.8em;
  top: -.1em;
  border-color: grey;
}

.slider__next::after {
  content: "";
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  right: 2.8em;
  top: -.1em;
  border-color: grey;
}

.birthday__count,
.collegues__count {
  position: absolute;
  top: 342px;
  display: flex;
  left: 50%;
  /* width: 50px;
  font-size: 12px;
  transform: translateX(-50%);*/
}


/*---------------------
---------SLICK---------
----------------------*/

.slide {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.slider-wrapper,
.slider-wrapper2 {
  margin: 10px auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.slick-prev {
  position: absolute;
  top: 21em;
  left: 60%;
}

.slick-next {
  position: absolute;
  top: 21em;
  left: 30%;
}

.slide-count {
  width: 60px;
  margin: 20px auto 0px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.section__video {
  border-bottom: 2px solid lightgrey;
  min-height: 450px;
  margin: 5px 20px 0px 0px;
}

.slider-count {
  position: relative;
  transform: translateY(50%);
}

.slider {
  width: 1080px;
  margin: 20px;
}

.next,
.prev {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  margin: 0px 0px 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.next2,
.prev2 {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  margin: 0px 0px 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.next3,
.prev3 {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  margin: 0px 0px 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.next,
.next2 {
  left: 62%;
  background: #f8f8f8;
}

.prev,
.prev2 {
  left: 30%;
  background: #f8f8f8;
}

.prev3 {
  left: 40%;
}

.next3 {
  left: 57%;
}

.slide-size {
  margin: 5px;
  flex-basis: 0;
  flex-grow: 1;
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.button__line {
  width: 40px;
  height: 1px;
  background: black;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
}

.button__line-right {
  right: 50%;
}

.button__line-left::after {
  content: "";
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  right: 2.3em;
  top: -2px;
  border-color: black;
}

.button__line-left {
  left: 50%;
}

.button__line-right::after {
  content: "";
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(135deg);
  left: 2.3em;
  top: -2px;
  border-color: black;
}

.next:hover,
.prev:hover,
.next2:hover,
.prev2:hover,
.next3:hover,
.prev3:hover {
  border: #00a85d 1px solid;
}

.button__line:hover {
  background-color: #00a85d;
}

.count-color {
  color: #00a85d;
}

.next3 .button__line-right::after {
  content: "";
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(135deg);
  left: 2.3em;
  top: -2px;
  border-color: black;
}

.prev3 .button__line-left::after {
  content: "";
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  right: 2.3em;
  top: -2px;
  border-color: black;
}


/*---------------------
---------CLOCK---------
----------------------*/

.section__timeblock {
  position: relative;
  margin: 35px 0px 80px 10px;
}

.timeblock__count {
  position: absolute;
  top: 372px;
  left: 50%;
  display: flex;
  font-size: 12px;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.timeblock__header {
  text-align: left;
  margin: 40px 0 30px;
}

.timeblock__title {
  font-weight: 400;
  font-family: 'Stolzl', sans-serif;
}

.timeblock {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.timeblock__list {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-left: -30px;
}

.timeblock__text {
  margin: 0;
}

.timeblock__elem {
  padding: 5px;
}

.clock__timeblock {
  display: flex;
}

.block__timeblock {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-basis: 33%;
}

.timeblock-wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

.time {
  font-weight: bold;
}

#clock,
#clock2,
#clock3,
#clock4 {
  display: flex;
}

.prev4,
.next4 {
  width: 19px;
  height: 19px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 300px;
}

.prev4__arrow .next4__arrow {
  width: 19px;
  height: 19px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 300px;
}

.next4 {
  bottom: 25px;
}

.next4__arrow {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.slick-slide {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="main__section--slider clearfix">

  <section class="main__section--collegues">
    <h2 class="collegues__title">Новые сотрудники</h2>

    <div class="collegues__list slider-new">

      <div class="collegues__list-el">
        <div class="person__block">
          <div class="collegues__block--image">
            <img src="img/male.png" class="collegues__image">
          </div>

          <div>
            <div class="collegues__name">
              <a href="javascript:void(0);" target="_self" class="collegues__name-link">
                <p class="collegues__firstname">Константин</p>
                <p class="collegues__surname">Константинопольский</p>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="collegues__position">Финансовый аналитик</div>
            <div class="collegues__date">с <time>14.07.2018</time></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="collegues__list-el">
        <div class="person__block">
          <div class="collegues__block--image">
            <img src="img/female.png" class="collegues__image">
          </div>

          <div>
            <div class="collegues__name">
              <a href="javascript:void(0);" target="_self" class="collegues__name-link">
                <p class="collegues__firstname">Василиса</p>
                <p class="collegues__surname">Рождественская</p>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="collegues__position">Бухгалтер</div>
            <div class="collegues__date">с <time>29.06.2018</time></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="collegues__list-el">
        <div class="person__block">
          <div class="collegues__block--image">
            <img src="img/male.png" class="collegues__image">
          </div>

          <div>
            <div class="collegues__name">
              <a href="javascript:void(0);" target="_self" class="collegues__name-link">
                <p class="collegues__firstname">Александр</p>
                <p class="collegues__surname">Вешняков</p>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="collegues__position">Водитель</div>
            <div class="collegues__date">с <time>25.06.2018</time></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="collegues__list-el">
        <div class="person__block">
          <div class="collegues__block--image">
            <img src="img/male.png" class="collegues__image">
          </div>

          <div>
            <div class="collegues__name">
              <a href="javascript:void(0);" target="_self" class="collegues__name-link">
                <p class="collegues__firstname">Александр</p>
                <p class="collegues__surname">Тан</p>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="collegues__position">Секретарь</div>
            <div class="collegues__date">с <time>30.06.2018</time></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="collegues__list-el">
        <div class="person__block">
          <div class="collegues__block--image">
            <img src="img/male.png" class="collegues__image">
          </div>

          <div>
            <div class="collegues__name">
              <a href="javascript:void(0);" target="_self" class="collegues__name-link">
                <p class="collegues__firstname">Александр</p>
                <p class="collegues__surname">Тан</p>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="collegues__position">Секретарь</div>
            <div class="collegues__date">с <time>30.06.2018</time></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="collegues__list-el">
        <div class="person__block">
          <div class="collegues__block--image">
            <img src="img/male.png" class="collegues__image">
          </div>

          <div>
            <div class="collegues__name">
              <a href="javascript:void(0);" target="_self" class="collegues__name-link">
                <p class="collegues__firstname">Александр</p>
                <p class="collegues__surname">Тан</p>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="collegues__position">Секретарь</div>
            <div class="collegues__date">с <time>30.06.2018</time></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="slider-count">
      <div class="slide-count"><span id="count">01</span>/<span class="count-color">04</span></div>
      <div class="next"><span class="button__line button__line-right"></span></div>
      <div class="prev"><span class="button__line button__line-left"></span></div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section class="main__section--birthday">
    <h2 class="collegues__title">С днем рождения!</h2>

    <div class="collegues__birthday slider-birthday">

      <div class="collegues__list-el">
        <div class="person__block">
          <div class="collegues__block--image">
            <img src="img/male.png" class="collegues__image">
          </div>

          <div>
            <div class="collegues__name">
              <a href="javascript:void(0);" target="_self" class="collegues__name-link">
                <p class="collegues__firstname">Александр</p>
                <p class="collegues__surname">Громов</p>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="collegues__position">Водитель</div>
            <div class="collegues__date">5 июля</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="collegues__list-el">
        <div class="person__block">
          <div class="collegues__block--image">
            <img src="img/male.png" class="collegues__image">
          </div>

          <div>
            <div class="collegues__name">
              <a href="javascript:void(0);" target="_self" class="collegues__name-link">
                <p class="collegues__firstname">Михаил</p>
                <p class="collegues__surname">Решетников
                </p>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="collegues__position">Главный бухгалтер</div>
            <div class="collegues__date">29 июня</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="collegues__list-el">
        <div class="person__block">
          <div class="collegues__block--image">
            <img src="img/female.png" class="collegues__image">
          </div>

          <div>
            <div class="collegues__name">
              <a href="javascript:void(0);" target="_self" class="collegues__name-link">
                <p class="collegues__firstname">Анна</p>
                <p class="collegues__surname">Кочергина</p>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="collegues__position">Бухгалтер</div>
            <div class="collegues__date">5 июля</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="collegues__list-el">
        <div class="person__block">
          <div class="collegues__block--image">
            <img src="img/female.png" class="collegues__image">
          </div>

          <div>
            <div class="collegues__name">
              <a href="javascript:void(0);" target="_self" class="collegues__name-link">
                <p class="collegues__firstname">Анастасия</p>
                <p class="collegues__surname">Мишина</p>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="collegues__position">Разработчик</div>
            <div class="collegues__date">6 июля</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="slider-count">
      <div class="slide-count"><span id="count2">01</span>/<span class="count-color">02</span></div>
      <div class="next2"><span class="button__line button__line-right"></span></div>
      <div class="prev2"><span class="button__line button__line-left"></span></div>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Я сейчас не понял, на каком счетчике показывает не то значение? На 1 счетчике строго +1

Comment: Да, прописано +1, но происходит +3. Вместо 02/02 > 04/02

Comment: Вы что-то поправили? Потому что сейчас при клике происходит +1 и сдвигается карусель на 1.

Comment: @Lukas вот и я об этом говорю, что тут все работает правильно!

Comment: @Lukas случайно в slidesToScroll: 3 указала 1 вместо 3. По идее теперь будет эта ошибка. Нужно чтобы он листал по 3, а прибавлял 1

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.slider-new').slick({
    arrows: true,
    nextArrow: $('.next'),
    prevArrow: $('.prev'),
    infinite: false,
    slidesToShow: 3,
    slidesToScroll: 3
  });
});

$(".next").on('click', function() {
 let count =  +$("#countEmpl").text();
 let countMax = +$('#countEmplColor').text();
  if (count < countMax){
 $("#countEmpl").text("0" + (count + 1));
    }
});
$(".prev").on('click', function() {
 let count =  +$("#countEmpl").text();
  if (count != 1 ){
 $("#countEmpl").text("0" + (count - 1));
    }
});
 

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.slider-birthday').slick({
    arrows: true,
    nextArrow: $('.next2'),
    prevArrow: $('.prev2'),
    infinite: false,
    slidesToShow: 3,
    slidesToScroll: 3
  });
});
$(".slider-birthday").on('afterChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide) {
  if (currentSlide == 0) {
    $("#count2").text("0" + (currentSlide + 1));
  } else {
    $("#count2").text("0" + (currentSlide + 1));
  }

});
```

```css
.main__section--slider {
  margin: 20px 0px 0px 10px;
  background: #f8f8f8;
  padding: 0px 0px 20px 0px;
}

.owl-item {
  width: 10%;
}

.main__section--collegues,
.main__section--birthday {
  width: 49%;
  float: left;
  margin: 2em 0px 1.1em;
  position: relative;
}

.main__section--birthday {
  border-left: 1px solid grey;
}

.collegues__list,
.collegues__birthday {
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
}

.collegues__list-el {
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.collegues__title {
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

.collegues__firstname,
.collegues__surname {
  margin: 0px;
}

.collegues__name {
  font: bold 14px/1.1 'Stolzl', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

.collegues__name-link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
}

.collegues__name-link:active {
  color: #000;
}

.collegues__position {
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.collegues__date,
.collegues__position {
  font: normal 14px/1.1 'Stolzl', sans-serif;
  color: grey;
}

.collegues__birthday>.owl-nav:hover {
  color: #00a85d;
}

.collegues__block--image {}

.collegues__image {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
}


/*---------------------
---------CLEARFIX------
----------------------*/

.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}


/*----------------------
---------ARROW----------
-----------------------*/

.owl-next:hover,
.owl-prev:hover {
  border-color: #00a85d;
}

.slider__next,
.slider__prev {
  width: 3em;
  height: 2px;
  background: grey;
  border: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
}

.slider__prev {
  right: 50%;
}

.slider__next {
  left: 50%;
}

.navigation__btn {
  position: relative;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid grey;
  margin: 0px 3.5em 0px 3.5em;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.navigation__btn:hover {
  border-color: #00a85d;
}

.slider__prev::after {
  content: "";
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(135deg);
  left: 2.8em;
  top: -.1em;
  border-color: grey;
}

.slider__next::after {
  content: "";
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  right: 2.8em;
  top: -.1em;
  border-color: grey;
}

.birthday__count,
.collegues__count {
  position: absolute;
  top: 342px;
  display: flex;
  left: 50%;
  /* width: 50px;
  font-size: 12px;
  transform: translateX(-50%);*/
}


/*---------------------
---------SLICK---------
----------------------*/

.slide {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.slider-wrapper,
.slider-wrapper2 {
  margin: 10px auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.slick-prev {
  position: absolute;
  top: 21em;
  left: 60%;
}

.slick-next {
  position: absolute;
  top: 21em;
  left: 30%;
}

.slide-count {
  width: 60px;
  margin: 20px auto 0px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.section__video {
  border-bottom: 2px solid lightgrey;
  min-height: 450px;
  margin: 5px 20px 0px 0px;
}

.slider-count {
  position: relative;
  transform: translateY(50%);
}

.slider {
  width: 1080px;
  margin: 20px;
}

.next,
.prev {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  margin: 0px 0px 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.next2,
.prev2 {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  margin: 0px 0px 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.next3,
.prev3 {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  margin: 0px 0px 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.next,
.next2 {
  left: 62%;
  background: #f8f8f8;
}

.prev,
.prev2 {
  left: 30%;
  background: #f8f8f8;
}

.prev3 {
  left: 40%;
}

.next3 {
  left: 57%;
}

.slide-size {
  margin: 5px;
  flex-basis: 0;
  flex-grow: 1;
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.button__line {
  width: 40px;
  height: 1px;
  background: black;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
}

.button__line-right {
  right: 50%;
}

.button__line-left::after {
  content: "";
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  right: 2.3em;
  top: -2px;
  border-color: black;
}

.button__line-left {
  left: 50%;
}

.button__line-right::after {
  content: "";
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(135deg);
  left: 2.3em;
  top: -2px;
  border-color: black;
}

.next:hover,
.prev:hover,
.next2:hover,
.prev2:hover,
.next3:hover,
.prev3:hover {
  border: #00a85d 1px solid;
}

.button__line:hover {
  background-color: #00a85d;
}

.count-color {
  color: #00a85d;
}

.next3 .button__line-right::after {
  content: "";
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(135deg);
  left: 2.3em;
  top: -2px;
  border-color: black;
}

.prev3 .button__line-left::after {
  content: "";
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  right: 2.3em;
  top: -2px;
  border-color: black;
}


/*---------------------
---------CLOCK---------
----------------------*/

.section__timeblock {
  position: relative;
  margin: 35px 0px 80px 10px;
}

.timeblock__count {
  position: absolute;
  top: 372px;
  left: 50%;
  display: flex;
  font-size: 12px;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.timeblock__header {
  text-align: left;
  margin: 40px 0 30px;
}

.timeblock__title {
  font-weight: 400;
  font-family: 'Stolzl', sans-serif;
}

.timeblock {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.timeblock__list {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-left: -30px;
}

.timeblock__text {
  margin: 0;
}

.timeblock__elem {
  padding: 5px;
}

.clock__timeblock {
  display: flex;
}

.block__timeblock {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-basis: 33%;
}

.timeblock-wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

.time {
  font-weight: bold;
}

#clock,
#clock2,
#clock3,
#clock4 {
  display: flex;
}

.prev4,
.next4 {
  width: 19px;
  height: 19px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 300px;
}

.prev4__arrow .next4__arrow {
  width: 19px;
  height: 19px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 300px;
}

.next4 {
  bottom: 25px;
}

.next4__arrow {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.slick-slide {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="main__section--slider clearfix">

  <section class="main__section--collegues">
    <h2 class="collegues__title">Новые сотрудники</h2>

    <div class="collegues__list slider-new">

      <div class="collegues__list-el">
        <div class="person__block">
          <div class="collegues__block--image">
            <img src="img/male.png" class="collegues__image">
          </div>

          <div>
            <div class="collegues__name">
              <a href="javascript:void(0);" target="_self" class="collegues__name-link">
                <p class="collegues__firstname">Константин</p>
                <p class="collegues__surname">Константинопольский</p>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="collegues__position">Финансовый аналитик</div>
            <div class="collegues__date">с <time>14.07.2018</time></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="collegues__list-el">
        <div class="person__block">
          <div class="collegues__block--image">
            <img src="img/female.png" class="collegues__image">
          </div>

          <div>
            <div class="collegues__name">
              <a href="javascript:void(0);" target="_self" class="collegues__name-link">
                <p class="collegues__firstname">Василиса</p>
                <p class="collegues__surname">Рождественская</p>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="collegues__position">Бухгалтер</div>
            <div class="collegues__date">с <time>29.06.2018</time></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="collegues__list-el">
        <div class="person__block">
          <div class="collegues__block--image">
            <img src="img/male.png" class="collegues__image">
          </div>

          <div>
            <div class="collegues__name">
              <a href="javascript:void(0);" target="_self" class="collegues__name-link">
                <p class="collegues__firstname">Александр</p>
                <p class="collegues__surname">Вешняков</p>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="collegues__position">Водитель</div>
            <div class="collegues__date">с <time>25.06.2018</time></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="collegues__list-el">
        <div class="person__block">
          <div class="collegues__block--image">
            <img src="img/male.png" class="collegues__image">
          </div>

          <div>
            <div class="collegues__name">
              <a href="javascript:void(0);" target="_self" class="collegues__name-link">
                <p class="collegues__firstname">Александр</p>
                <p class="collegues__surname">Тан</p>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="collegues__position">Секретарь</div>
            <div class="collegues__date">с <time>30.06.2018</time></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="collegues__list-el">
        <div class="person__block">
          <div class="collegues__block--image">
            <img src="img/male.png" class="collegues__image">
          </div>

          <div>
            <div class="collegues__name">
              <a href="javascript:void(0);" target="_self" class="collegues__name-link">
                <p class="collegues__firstname">Александр</p>
                <p class="collegues__surname">Тан</p>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="collegues__position">Секретарь</div>
            <div class="collegues__date">с <time>30.06.2018</time></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="collegues__list-el">
        <div class="person__block">
          <div class="collegues__block--image">
            <img src="img/male.png" class="collegues__image">
          </div>

          <div>
            <div class="collegues__name">
              <a href="javascript:void(0);" target="_self" class="collegues__name-link">
                <p class="collegues__firstname">Александр</p>
                <p class="collegues__surname">Тан</p>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="collegues__position">Секретарь</div>
            <div class="collegues__date">с <time>30.06.2018</time></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="slider-count">
      <div class="slide-count"><span id="countEmpl">01</span>/<span id="countEmplColor" class="count-color">04</span></div>
      <div class="next"><span class="button__line button__line-right"></span></div>
      <div class="prev"><span class="button__line button__line-left"></span></div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section class="main__section--birthday">
    <h2 class="collegues__title">С днем рождения!</h2>

    <div class="collegues__birthday slider-birthday">

      <div class="collegues__list-el">
        <div class="person__block">
          <div class="collegues__block--image">
            <img src="img/male.png" class="collegues__image">
          </div>

          <div>
            <div class="collegues__name">
              <a href="javascript:void(0);" target="_self" class="collegues__name-link">
                <p class="collegues__firstname">Александр</p>
                <p class="collegues__surname">Громов</p>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="collegues__position">Водитель</div>
            <div class="collegues__date">5 июля</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="collegues__list-el">
        <div class="person__block">
          <div class="collegues__block--image">
            <img src="img/male.png" class="collegues__image">
          </div>

          <div>
            <div class="collegues__name">
              <a href="javascript:void(0);" target="_self" class="collegues__name-link">
                <p class="collegues__firstname">Михаил</p>
                <p class="collegues__surname">Решетников
                </p>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="collegues__position">Главный бухгалтер</div>
            <div class="collegues__date">29 июня</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="collegues__list-el">
        <div class="person__block">
          <div class="collegues__block--image">
            <img src="img/female.png" class="collegues__image">
          </div>

          <div>
            <div class="collegues__name">
              <a href="javascript:void(0);" target="_self" class="collegues__name-link">
                <p class="collegues__firstname">Анна</p>
                <p class="collegues__surname">Кочергина</p>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="collegues__position">Бухгалтер</div>
            <div class="collegues__date">5 июля</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="collegues__list-el">
        <div class="person__block">
          <div class="collegues__block--image">
            <img src="img/female.png" class="collegues__image">
          </div>

          <div>
            <div class="collegues__name">
              <a href="javascript:void(0);" target="_self" class="collegues__name-link">
                <p class="collegues__firstname">Анастасия</p>
                <p class="collegues__surname">Мишина</p>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="collegues__position">Разработчик</div>
            <div class="collegues__date">6 июля</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="slider-count">
      <div class="slide-count"><span id="count2">01</span>/<span class="count-color">02</span></div>
      <div class="next2"><span class="button__line button__line-right"></span></div>
      <div class="prev2"><span class="button__line button__line-left"></span></div>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```